# Magento not handling new lines \n \n\n

Tags: magento

I am importing products with descriptions that include html code. It seems to display proper tags like `<b>text</b>` but is not dealing with `\n` for new lines and is instead printing \n in the product descritptions.

How does one get magento handle these type of "tags"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use nl2br function at the time of importing

check this url http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

hope this will help you

```
<?php
$stringValue = "foo isn't\n bar";
echo nl2br($stringValue);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
foo isn't<br />
 bar
```

Comment: Any ideas how to use this with magmi import for magento?